# JQuery Datatables click event not working for pages except 1

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using [JQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net) for my application. I have a simple code which displays all my clients and a script which fires on the click of table row. Now, the problem is, this works fine for the first page, however, for all the other pages click event on the row is not identified. Please find below the code for the datatable and the script library.

```
// viewAllClients.php

<table id="view_all_entries" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $values = Client::all();
    foreach ($values as $value)
        {?>
<tr class="options" data-val="{{$value->name}}" data-id="{{$value->id}}">
        <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->city}}</td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>  
</tbody>
</table>

//default.js

$('#view_all_entries').DataTable( {
            "aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
            "iDisplayLength": 30,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        } );

$('#view_all_entries .options').click(function(){
var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
document.location.href = $('#route_path').val()+'/'+id + '/edit';
});
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, well, based on the answer by Halcyon, I figured out that I needed a minor change for event delegation. I hope the following code helps other stucked with the same problem.

```
//default.js    
$('body').delegate('#view_all_entries .options', 'click', function () {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
  document.location.href = $('#route_path').val()+'/'+id + '/edit';
});
```

Comment: Ah yea, that's the one I meant. In newer version of jQuery it's been replaced by `on`. So I think `$('#view_all_entries .options').on("click", .. );` does it as well.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#view_all_entries .options')` matches DOM Nodes that are currently on the page. Once you go to the next page a new set of DOM Nodes is created. If you also want those to be clickable you must added the `click` handler.

I think there is a way to automatically do this in jQuery but the straight forward approach is to add the click handler whenever the data changes.

You can bind to the `page` event to know when a new page is loaded: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html

It's little bit like this row callback exmaple: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

Comment: Votes up for the answer. Just gave me the right idea. Adding an answer to my question for future references.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and this is my implementation in Asp.Net and Jquery. I have a grid-view and an Edit button inside the Item Template. I'm making an ajax function call. You need to use a delegate.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdRegPeople" runat="server" class="display table table-hover table-condensed" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ClientIDMode="Static" OnPageIndexChanging="GrdRegPeople_PageIndexChanging">
  <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Reg_id" HeaderText="Reg.ID">
          <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
          <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
       </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Reg_email" HeaderText="Email">
           <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company">
           <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Reg_position" HeaderText="Position">
           <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-primary activeButton" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

```
 $("body").delegate("#GrdRegPeople .activeButton", "click", function (e) {
            //Write Your Code here..
                                }
        });
```